# Escape character in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some server information in ASP that I need to pass through AJAX. However, the server name has a back slash.

```
var concode = "<%response.write(concode)%>";
```

But when stepping through the code the server name does not have the back slash.

How do I fix it so that the back slash stays in the server name?

Comment: What language? VB.net? Classic Asp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The escape character is the backslash: [JavaScript Special Characters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_special_characters.asp)

If this is classic ASP:

```
var concode = "<%=Replace(concode, "\", "\\")%>";
```

If it's VB.NET:

```
var concode = "<%=concode.Replace("\", "\\")%>";
```

**Note:** Depending on exactly how you've coded your page, those nested quotes may give the ASP parser fits.

Comment: My language was Classic Asp and your method worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

either escape the backslash `\\` == `\`, or use `encodeURI(servername)`